# Running a script when users connect through ssh

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I am installing a server; I am preparing it for SSH traffic.
I would like a script to be run (a dialog with the freshly connected user) every time a user from a certain group connects.
How do I do this (kind of like in the SSH hook post)?

I want a certain a group, which i will just call users, who just want to launch a game server or something like that, to be able to do so with minimal headache. And my idea is to make a script, which launches everytime they connect, that takes their hand and allows them to execute different actions, all centered around that game server thing. I don't want admins to be bothered every time by that script.

Comment: Do you want it run, however they login (ssh, or local). This is the easier solution. Or only when they login via `ssh`. This is a little bit harder, but not too hard.

Comment: Look at [How to execute a system-wide script upon any ssh login (with OpenSSH)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/153445/how-to-execute-a-system-wide-script-upon-any-ssh-login-with-openssh)

Comment: Well, i would like it to be executed, whenever a user of a certain group  logs in :) (added that to main message) but apart from that it is a duplicate indeed...

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Since i want it run for only i certain group of users, i do not care whether it is local or not. Whatever is easier !

Comment: You say, you want an interactive dialogue with the user, when they log in (so computer will ask question). Is this correct? What happens next, do they get a bash prompt?

Comment: I am worried that the question is too abstract. Can you add to the bottom, some background. What are you trying to achieve (a non-technical explanation, that your users, and my mum, would understand). This may help us to see what type of solution will be best for you (as I said, there is more than one way to do this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not with the **/etc/profile** file on the server, with one condition?

For example: Only for the group **player**, the script **/etc/profile-grp/player** is executed (sourced from /etc/profile) . 
It writes the date in a log file (~/log) of the user's directory.

```
grp=player

# Write a script
sudo mkdir /etc/profile-grp
echo "date >> ~/log" | sudo tee /etc/profile-grp/${grp}

# Script permissions
sudo chown root:${grp} /etc/profile-grp/${grp}
sudo chmod 640 /etc/profile-grp/${grp}

# In /etc/profile
echo " 
if ( groups | grep ${grp} > /dev/null); then
   . /etc/profile-grp/${grp}
fi" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile

unset grp
```

- Only the player group (and root) can read the script.
- Free to edit the script. Only root can change it.

Answer (score 0):

Some Options:

- Change each users login shell, to be the interactive script.
- Edit/copy each users .profile, this is run each time that bash is started when it stops the user gets their prompt.
- Edit users ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, so to tell ssh to run a special command when user connects. This is like option 1, but for `ssh` only. It can also be used to allow many people with different keys to log into same account, but have different action (user separation, by action).

Comment: The thing is that there could be more than 100 guys :/ I guess i could switch to keys, but i still want a good portion of the users to have their own accounts (all spawning them to the same Folder)

Comment: I am worried that the question is too abstract. Can you add to the bottom, some background. What are you trying to achieve (a non-technical explanation, that your users, and my mum, would understand). This may help us to see what type of solution will be best for you (as I said, there is more than one way to do this).

Comment: Well, i have edited my message to explicitely say how why i need this and how i want it. Was that not enough ?